# BeautifulSoup, how to properly use decompose()

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to remove comment tags from local .xml files using the BeautifulSoup library.

**sample XML**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
  <!-- remove this -->
 <to>Tove</to>
 <from>Jani</from>
 <heading>Reminder</heading>
 <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

**python**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from bs4 import Comment

soup = BS(open("sample.xml"))

comments=soup.find_all(string=lambda text:isinstance(text,Comment))

for c in comments:
    c.decompose()
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Comment' object has no attribute 'decompose'
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: @DavidZemens ... I would highly advise not to follow the dup link as one should not run [regex on X|HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1422451). My answer to OP would have been to run XSLT using Python's lxml. See [demo fiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2Cn).

Comment: @Parfait see the highest-upvoted answer on the dupe link, which does not use regex

Comment: Solution: Use extract() in place of decompose()